# Revolution Slider flashing in Firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using Revolution Slider in Wordpress on a site and having an issue just in Firefox.

The slider works great everywhere but Firefox. When the slide transitions to a new slide, the previous slide will flash through for a couple milliseconds.

Here is the url:
http://www.skysourceinternational.com

Anyone seen this issue with Revolution Slider before??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using old version of [Revolution Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380) maybe **3.0.6**, this bug is fixed in version **3.0.8**, Now latest version is **4.1.4**, Please update to latest version.

#### Or

if you're using **Lazy Loading** in **Full Width Layout** change it, then Slider will work correctly.